# SQL - SELECT WITH FILTER

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
TId  || Status
--------------
4789    12
4789    5
4789    5
3696    12
3696    12
4568    12
4568    12
```

I have this table and what i want to get is to select all TId where the status are all = 12.

My result expected is like this:

```
3696
4568
```

Someone can help me with this pls?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by the `tid` column and take only those having zero times a `status = 12`

```
select tid
from your_table
group by tid
having sum(case when status <> 12 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

An aggregation and `having` clause is a good way to approach this.  I would compare the minimum and maximum values:

```
select t.tid
from table t
group by t.tid
having min(status) = max(status) and min(status) = 12;
```

But there are other approaches.  If you have a table of `tid`, you can use `exists` and `not exists`:

```
select tids.*
from tids
where not exists (select 1 from table t2 where t2.tid = tids.tid and t2.tid <> 12);
```

This approach can take advantage of an index on `tids` and doesn't require aggregation.